# Как сделать взаимодействие сенсоров в box2d?

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d

Я не могу сообразить,  как сделать так, чтобы при взаимодействии сенсоров платформа стала активной. что-то вроде этого:

```
BeginContact { if (sensorA && sensorB) platform.getBody().setActive(true);}
```

но не понимаю, как это сделать. Помогите пожалуйста

```
// в нем описываю все объекты, которые буду создавать в GameStage
public class WorldUtils {

    public static World createWorld() {
        return new World(Constants.WORLD_GRAVITY, true);
    }

    public static Body createPlatform(World world) {
        // тут говорится, в какой позиции и какое будет тело (работает хорошо)
        SpawnType spawnType = RandomUtils.getRandomSpawnType();
        // создаю bodyDef
        BodyDef bodyDef = new BodyDef();
        bodyDef.type = BodyDef.BodyType.StaticBody;
        bodyDef.position.set(new Vector2(GameStage.pointToCreate, spawnType.getY()));// расположена в этой точке

        // создаю фигуру
        PolygonShape shape = new PolygonShape();//видимая фигура
        FixtureDef fixtureDef = new FixtureDef();
        fixtureDef.density = spawnType.getDensity();
        fixtureDef.shape = shape; //использует shape

        shape.setAsBox(spawnType.getWidth() / 2, spawnType.getHeight() / 2); // размер

        // создаю фигуру, которая будет сенсором
        PolygonShape polygonShapeSensor = new PolygonShape();
        polygonShapeSensor.setAsBox(Constants.PLATFORM_WIDTH/2+0.5f, Constants.PLATFORM_HEIGHT/2-1.5f,
                new Vector2(Constants.PLATFORM_WIDTH/2-0.5f, Constants.PLATFORM_HEIGHT/2-2f), bodyDef.angle);//размер, позиция и текущий угол

        FixtureDef myPolygonFixtureDef = new FixtureDef();
        myPolygonFixtureDef.shape = polygonShapeSensor;
        myPolygonFixtureDef.isSensor = true;// сенсор, физически он не сталкивается

        Body body = world.createBody(bodyDef);/создают тело с bodyDef
        body.createFixture(fixtureDef);
        body.createFixture(myPolygonFixtureDef);
        body.resetMassData();
        PlatformUserData userData = new PlatformUserData(spawnType.getWidth(), spawnType.getHeight());
        body.setUserData(userData);// в userData отмечается, что это платформа
        shape.dispose();
        return body;
    }


    public static Body createCharacter(World world) {
        // то же самое
        BodyDef bodyDef = new BodyDef();
        bodyDef.type = BodyDef.BodyType.DynamicBody;
        bodyDef.position.set(new Vector2(Constants.CHARACTER_X, Constants.CHARACTER_Y));

        PolygonShape shape = new PolygonShape();
        shape.setAsBox(Constants.CHARACTER_WIDTH / 2, Constants.CHARACTER_HEIGHT / 2);
        PolygonShape polygonShapeSensor = new PolygonShape();
        polygonShapeSensor.setAsBox(Constants.CHARACTER_WIDTH/2+0.5f, Constants.CHARACTER_HEIGHT/2-1.5f,
                new Vector2(Constants.CHARACTER_WIDTH/2-0.5f, Constants.CHARACTER_HEIGHT/2-2f), bodyDef.angle);

        FixtureDef myPolygonFixtureDef = new FixtureDef();
        myPolygonFixtureDef.shape = polygonShapeSensor;
        myPolygonFixtureDef.isSensor = true;

        Body body = world.createBody(bodyDef);
        body.setGravityScale(Constants.CHARACTER_GRAVITY_SCALE);
        body.createFixture(shape, Constants.CHARACTER_DENSITY);
        body.createFixture(myPolygonFixtureDef);
        body.resetMassData();
        body.setUserData(new CharacterUserData(Constants.CHARACTER_WIDTH, Constants.CHARACTER_HEIGHT));
        shape.dispose();
        body.setBullet(true);
        body.setSleepingAllowed(false);
        return body;
    }
}




public class GameStage extends Stage implements ContactListener {// в нем все происходит

...............................................................

    @Override
    public void beginContact(Contact contact) {// если коллизии начинают взаимодействовать
        Body a = contact.getFixtureA().getBody();
        Body b = contact.getFixtureB().getBody();


        if ((BodyUtils.bodyIsRunner(a) && BodyUtils.bodyIsGround(b)) ||
                (BodyUtils.bodyIsGround(a) && BodyUtils.bodyIsRunner(b))) {


        }

    }
}



public class BodyUtils {// определяет, где платформа, а где пкрсонаж

    public static boolean bodyIsRunner(Body body) {
        UserData userData = (UserData) body.getUserData();
        return userData!=null && userData.getUserDataType() == UserDataType.CHARACTER;
    }

    public static boolean bodyIsGround (Body body) {
        UserData userData = (UserData) body.getUserData();
        return userData != null && userData.getUserDataType() == UserDataType.PLATFORM;
    }
}
```

Comment: Вы не думали о том, чтобы пояснить код?

Comment: Помогите пожалуйста( нужно всего лишь сделать так, чтобы можно было пройти сквозь платформы с одной сторны